# I am trying to find times in an array of objects using the value of my input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, ajax, dom

I will try my best to explain this.  I have an input field which allows the user to enter a certain time.  I also have an array of attractions that have times with them.  Once the user enters a time and clicks a button, all arrtactions with that time should load to dom.  The event listener is working, but every attraction is printing, even the ones without times. Below is what I have so far.  I believe I am just missing some minor details.

```
<input id="timeInput" type="text" placeholder="Ex: 1:00 PM">
    <button id="timeBtn">Show me Scheduled Events!</button>



let timeTest = [];
let timesArray = [];
let timeSearch = document.getElementById("timeInput");
$('#timeBtn').on('click',((e) => {
timeTest.push(timeSearch.value);
let timeSplit = timeTest[1].split(":");
let hourSelected = timeSplit[0];
let morningOrEvening = timeSplit[1];
controller.getType()
.then((data) => {
    for(let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { 
        if (data[i].times !== undefined) {
            if (timeValueCheck(data[i].times)) {
                timesArray.push(data[i]);
            }
        else {
            timesArray.push(data[i]);
        }
    }}
    timesArray.forEach(attraction =>{
        $('#output').append(attrHBS(attraction));
        console.log(attraction);
        }
     );
    }
);
}));


let timeValueCheck= (timesArray) => {
    let timeSplit = timeTest[1].split(":");
    let hourSelected = timeSplit[0];
    let morningOrEvening = timeSplit[1];
    for (let i=0; i < timesArray.length; i++) {
        let splitArray = timesArray[i].split(":");
        console.log("super", splitArray);
        if (hourSelected === splitArray[0]){
            console.log("mega",hourSelected, splitArray[0]);
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
};


// this is what is inside controller.js

module.exports.getType = (attrData) => {
//creating new Promise to load when used in other functions
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
//getting our data from two ajax calls, attractions and attraction types
let p1 = factory.getAttractionData();
let p2 = factory.getAttTypes();
// empty array to push data into once we have manipulated it
let newDataWithTypes = [];
//promise all to get both data types before using them.
    Promise.all([p1,p2])
    .then((attrData) => { 
        // loop over the first array, all 132 attractions
        attrData[0].forEach(allAttractions => {
            // loop over second array, the 8 types
            attrData[1].forEach(typeofAttractions => {
                // if statement to add the types to each attraction based on their type id!
                    if (allAttractions.type_id === typeofAttractions.id) {
                        allAttractions.type = typeofAttractions.name;
                        // pushes to the array on 32
                        newDataWithTypes.push(allAttractions); 
                    }
                });
            });
            resolve(newDataWithTypes);
        }
    );
});
};
```

Comment: What is `controller`?

Comment: Im using browserify and grunt, so I have a bunch of modules set up. controller.getType() is coming from my controller module thats doing an ajax call to firebase that has my JSON data

Comment: You might want to see if you can put enough code in to make this an [mcve].  Because `controller` is undefined, anyone trying to answer this may have a tough time replicating the issue or testing their answer

Comment: i could give the controller code if you would like to look at it.

Comment: You're missing the point.  Your question has no real answers because no-one (except you) can run the code as-is.

Answer (score 0):

Array's index in javascript begins with 0.I think this is the problem.
try this

```
let timeSplit = timeTest[0].split(":");...
```

instead of

```
let timeSplit = timeTest[1].split(":");...
```

Comment: that isnt changing anything. if i click the button without entering a time, ill get all 27 that only have times in my console. If I add a time, ill get either all or 53

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't this line be '0':

```
let timeSplit = timeTest[0].split(":")
```

Comment: that isnt changing anything. if i click the button without entering a time, ill get all 27 that only have times in my console. If I add a time, ill get either all or 53.